# Localizable.strings with special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localizable.strings

I have a Localizable.strings file with string:

```
"m3h" = "m\u00B3/h";
```

It should return me m³/h, but I get mu00B3/h instead. How to get a string from Localizable.strings file that contains special characters?

Comment: Could you show how are you reading the localized string files? Since NSSting converts all unicode to proper strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you ask the person to give the localized strings file with proper values not what you have currently in unicodes:

Say the file should contain this:

> "m3h" = "m³/h";